# pipe() and then() documentation vs reality in jQuery 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

### Update: This question is now out of date as the documentation is accurate and up to date.

I've been exploring the jQuery Deferred/Promise API for a bit and I'm very confused about the differences between `pipe()` and `then()` philosophically and in the jQuery documentation.  I've found that pipe() is just an alias for then() as of jQuery 1.8.

From jQuery source:

```
// Keep pipe for back-compat
promise.pipe = promise.then;
```

Yet the documentation is completely different for `pipe()` and `then()` as they supposedly have entirely different uses.

Description for `then()`:

> Description: Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved or rejected.

Description for `pipe()`:

> Description: Utility method to filter and/or chain Deferreds.

I understand that historically they had slightly different behavior, but in the entirety of the [documentation for pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) or the [documentation for then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), it doesn't even say that these two functions do the exact same thing now.

So, here's my two part question:

1. Why does the documentation between `pipe()` and `then()` differ as of jQuery 1.8?
2. Why does `then()` return a **new** deferred object?  This behavior is completely undocumented (the [docs just say it returns a Deferred, not that it's a new one](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)).  I understand that it has utility in doing so (namely to implement all of `pipe()`'s features), but philosophically why is it the case?  It's unnecessary given the description of `then()` (to attach handlers).

**Update**

I'll even go so far as to say the `then()` docs are misleading and inaccurate:

> Since deferred.then **returns the deferred object**, other methods of the deferred object can be chained to this one, including additional .then() methods.

Maybe it's just vague, but it implies it returns the deferred object you called `then()` on for chaining, when in reality it returns an entirely new object....

**Update Again**

Seems the documentation is simply wrong/out of date!  So that answers why the documentation makes no mention of them being the same thing.  However, my second question still stands.  Is the reason `then()` returns a **new** deferred simply so that it and `pipe()` can be made equivalent?

Comment: +1 Why would *anybody* want to close this as being "too localized"? This is a fantastic question!!

Comment: I think the biggest issue with the docs for this part of the API is to not just explain that it's a basic CommonJS Promise/A implementation and refer people to somewhere else for an explanation of promises. The word "promise" does not even appear on the "then" page.

Comment: @Joseph, right now it is, but when the documentation gets updated a few days/hours from now it might not be anymore. I cannot predict what the new documentation will say, though, but I do think updating the question so it focuses less on the docs and more on the behavior change will prevent others from voting to close it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Well, the main point of the question *is* about the difference between `pipe` and `then`. The doc's inconsistencies is just a byproduct.

Comment: side note: `$.Deferred()` and `new $.Deferred()` are the same thing. the `new` is optional according to the documentation.

Comment: This question should be updated so that it doesn't refer to the outdated documentation, but otherwise, this is still a useful question / answer thread.

Comment: related: [When should I use jQuery deferred's “then” method and when should I use the “pipe” method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9583783/1048572)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The documentation update for jQuery 1.8 is not online yet.

According to [this recent blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/):

> We’re in the process of updating the API documentation for all the
>   changes to 1.8, but for now you can refer back to the changelog in the
>   [jQuery 1.8 announcement](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) to see what’s changed.

*Update:* Yes, `then()` returns a new `Deferred` because [it is equivalent to `pipe()` now](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11010). I'm pretty confident the documentation update will clarify this soon.

*Further update for completeness:* The documentation was recently updated and now says for [pipe()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/):

> **Deprecation Notice:** As of jQuery 1.8, the `deferred.pipe()` method is deprecated. The `deferred.then()` method, which replaces it, should
>   be used instead.

And for [then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

> **Prior to jQuery 1.8**, the arguments could be a function or an array of functions.
>
> [...]
>
> **As of jQuery 1.8**, the `deferred.then()` method returns a new promise that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a
>   function, replacing the now-deprecated `deferred.pipe()` method. The
>   `doneFilter` and `failFilter` functions filter the original deferred's
>   resolved / rejected status and values. The `progressFilter` function
>   filters any calls to the original deferred's `notify` or `notifyWith`
>   methods. These filter functions can return a new value to be passed
>   along to the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks, or they can
>   return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will
>   pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's
>   callbacks. If the filter function used is `null`, or not specified,
>   the promise will be resolved or rejected with the same values as the
>   original.

Comment: Unless I'm smoking crack, someone is, actually, updating the docs right now :) I was about to make a comment and then everything was different.

Comment: @Adam, and I'm afraid I have to close this question as [too localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4818/164403). Sorry, no harm meant.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi please don't - there's useful commentary to be made about the change.

Comment: @Alnitak, fair enough, but the question will have to be updated then (now it's all about doc inconsistencies).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Why in G-D's name would you consider this question "too localized"?

Comment: @Joseph, I answered under the question: Right now it's too tied to the docs, which are in the process of being updated, apparently as we speak. Refocusing the question can help.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Very fair, I think "The docs are just wrong" is a great explanation as to, you know, why they _are wrong_!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Can you perhaps comment on my second question?  Why does then() return a new deferred?  Is that simply so you can make then() and pipe() actually be the same thing?

Comment: @Adam, yes, `then()` returns a new Deferred because `pipe()` does, and they're the same thing now. `pipe()` is a little more complicated than the old `then()`, I tried to explain it once in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10253192/464709). Maybe it can help.

Comment: Of course, the documentation has been updated since this answer was submitted. Maybe an answer update is in order?