# Unable to reject jquery deferred with a piped function if it was resolved by a previous pipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

The code is pretty straight foreword:

```
  var handleNextPressedDeferred = $.Deferred();
  $('input:button').live('click',function(){
    console.log('resolving');
    return handleNextPressedDeferred.resolve();
  });

  handleNextPressedDeferred.pipe(function(){
    console.log('rejecting');
    return $.Deferred().reject();
  });

  var handleNextPressedPromise = handleNextPressedDeferred.promise();

  handleNextPressedPromise.done(function(){
    console.log('done');
  });
  handleNextPressedPromise.then(function(){
    console.log('then');
  });
  handleNextPressedPromise.fail(function(){
    console.log('fail');
  });
```

After the original button click resolves the deferred, I'm interested in rejecting it by the piped function.

The expected outcome when the button is clicked is:

- resolving
- rejecting
- fail

The actual outcome when the button is clicked is:

- resolving
- rejecting
- done
- then

What am I not understanding correctly here? I've tried a million variations of this and couldn't get it to work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.pipe` creates a new `Deferred`. In your code you are "connecting" `.done`, `.then` and `.fail` to the previous Deferred which is not rejected, that's why `.done` and `.then` are executed instead of `.fail`.

Try to replace this :

```
handleNextPressedDeferred.pipe(function(){
    console.log('rejecting');
    return $.Deferred().reject();
});

var handleNextPressedPromise = handleNextPressedDeferred.promise();
```

by

```
var handleNextPressedPromise = handleNextPressedDeferred.pipe(function(){
    console.log('rejecting');
    return $.Deferred().reject();
}).promise();
```

and it will work.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bfr8E/)

**Edit:**

I see you are using both `then` and `pipe` in your code. I don't know which version of jQuery you are using, but be careful that since jQuery 1.8, `pipe` and `then` are strictly equivalent and return both a new Deferred. `then` is no longer syntactic sugar for `.done` and `.fail`.

See [jQuery deferreds and promises - .then() vs .done()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436327/jquery-deferreds-and-promises-then-vs-done) and [pipe() and then() documentation vs reality in jQuery 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011925/pipe-and-then-documentation-vs-reality-in-jquery-1-8) for more information.