# Change data result while passing promise up chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

I am trying to migrate to using promises via jQuery. In my original code, I have a callback parameter that takes in modified data:

```
var getRss = function (url, fnLoad) {
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $(data).find('item').each(function (index) {
            items.push({
                title: $(this).find('title').text(),
                pubDate: $(this).find('pubDate').text()
            });
        });

        fnLoad(items);
    });
}
```

I tried changing to promise, but the "done" returns the unmodified data instead of the parsed one:

```
var getRss = function (url) {
    return $.get(url).done(function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $(data).find('item').each(function (index) {
            items.push({
                title: $(this).find('title').text(),
                pubDate: $(this).find('pubDate').text()
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Then using it like below but I get the original XML version, not the modified one that was converted to an object:

```
 getRss('/myurl').done(function (data) {
      $('body').append(template('#template', data));
  });
```

Comment: you're not accepting the `fnLoad` parameter in your second snippet.

Comment: Thx I fixe the typo. In the 2nd snippet, I'm expecting to get back the modified data that the previous "done" performed, but it's always returning the original data throughout the chain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (read the docs for [`pipe`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/), see [pipe() and then() documentation vs reality in jQuery 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12011925/1048572)):

```
function getRss(url) {
    return $.get(url).then(function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $(data).find('item').each(function (index) {
            items.push({
                title: $(this).find('title').text(),
                pubDate: $(this).find('pubDate').text()
            });
        });
        return items;
    });
}
```

…which works like

```
function getRss(url) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    $.get(url).done(function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $(data).find('item').each(function (index) {
            items.push({
                title: $(this).find('title').text(),
                pubDate: $(this).find('pubDate').text()
            });
        });
        dfrd.resolve(items);
    }).fail(dfrd.reject);
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```